# Java Swing using a main frame to get other components

Tags: java, swing, awt

Here I have this code below which reverses a text.

> TextFrame Class the main frame of my GUI

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;


public class TextFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    private Controls theControls;
    private ReverseText theReverseText;
    private InputOutputPanel theInputOutputPanel;

    public TextFrame(){

    this.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    theInputOutputPanel = new InputOutputPanel();
    theReverseText = new ReverseText(this);
    theControls = new Controls(theReverseText);

    this.getContentPane().add(theInputOutputPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    this.getContentPane().add(theControls, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    this.pack();
    this.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }


    public Controls getControls(){
    return this.theControls;
    }

    public InputOutputPanel getInputOutPanel(){
        return this.theInputOutputPanel;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // All we need to do is create the frame, as the constructor does everything required.
        TextFrame theFrame = new TextFrame();
//        theFrame.setSize(150, 150);
//        theFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

> InputOutPut Class Panel which handles the input and output

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class InputOutputPanel extends JPanel {

    private JTextField input;
    private JTextField output;
    private JTextField situation;

    public InputOutputPanel() {

        this.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2));
         this.add(new JLabel("header"));
        this.add(situation = new JTextField("Situation"));
        this.add(input = new JTextField("input text here"));
        this.add(output = new JTextField());


    }

    public void setSituation(String sit){
        situation.setText(sit);

    }

    public void setOutPut(String s){
    output.setText(s);
    }

    public String getInput(){
        return input.getText();


    }
}
```

> Controls class

```
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class Controls extends JPanel {
    private ReverseText reverseText; //the Event handler
    private TextFrame theTextFrame;  // the main frame to display the text

    public Controls(ReverseText reverseText){
    this.reverseText = reverseText;

    reverseText = new ReverseText(theTextFrame);

    JButton reversetheTextButton;       

    this.add(reversetheTextButton = new JButton("Text-Reverse"));
    reversetheTextButton.addActionListener(reverseText);   


    }

}
```

> ReverseText Class which is my event handler

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class ReverseText implements ActionListener {

    private TextFrame theTextFrame;
    private InputOutputPanel inputOutPanel;


    public ReverseText(TextFrame theTextFrame) {
        this.theTextFrame = theTextFrame;



    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    String buttonAction = event.getActionCommand();

    // trying to use the mainframe to get other components

    inputOutPanel = theTextFrame.getInputOutPanel(); // but this line complaining about null pointer error 

    String input = inputOutPanel.getInput();


    if (buttonAction.equals("Text-Reverse"))
        System.out.println("yes");
        inputOutPanel.setSituation(buttonAction);

        //Reverse The Text and send it to the Output
        String reversedText = new StringBuffer(input).reverse().toString();

        //
        inputOutPanel.setOutPut(reversedText);

    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here

    }

}
```

I want to use the mainframe in my event handler class to call these components butthis is not working.

I have get and set methods in my main Frame called TextFrame.

My question is how do I use my event handler class using the main frame cato take input from the GUI and reverse this input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never set the Controls TextFrame field with any TextFrame instance. You need to pass it into the Controls constructor via a parameter, just as you do the model.

```
public class Controls extends JPanel {
    private ReverseText reverseText; //the Event handler
    private TextFrame theTextFrame;  // the main frame to display the text

    // **** note changes to constructor
    public Controls(ReverseText reverseText, TextFrame theTextFrame){
        this.reverseText = reverseText;
        this.theTextFrame = textFrame;  // ***** added

        reverseText = new ReverseText(theTextFrame);
```

Then change:

```
theControls = new Controls(theReverseText, this); // **** note change
```

Comment: @EvelynDrew: you're welcome. For what it's worth though, the Control should not *be* a JPanel nor harbor view components such as JButtons.

Answer (score 0):

after new JButton(...), call setActionCommand on the button. Otherwise you just set the label, and the listener won't get an ActionCommand of the button even when the listener is fired.

Comment: the thing is my buttons work alright(checked and it is able to print a line using system .out ) because am using a string to get the command matched to the name of the button in my listener class, i want to be able to use the main frame to get those other components and then set these fields accordingly ?